# How to set boot device permanently in grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I need to write below commands on every pc restart:

```
grubrescue>set boot=(hd0,msdos7)
grubrescue>set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
grubrescue>insmod normal
grubrescue>normal
```

How to set boot device permanently in grub?

---

My /boot/grub/grub.cfg file:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd2,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=pl_PL
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd2,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-21-generic root=UUID=35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-21-generic
}
submenu 'Opcje zaawansowane dla systemu Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, za pomocą systemu Linux 4.18.0-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-21-generic-advanced-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 4.18.0-21-generic...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-21-generic root=UUID=35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-21-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-21-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-21-generic-recovery-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 4.18.0-21-generic...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-21-generic root=UUID=35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-21-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, za pomocą systemu Linux 4.18.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-20-generic-advanced-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 4.18.0-20-generic...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic root=UUID=35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-20-generic-recovery-35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 4.18.0-20-generic...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic root=UUID=35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-20-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd2,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd2,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35919a5d-0315-40fc-87d3-d4d75e6d118a
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (na /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-2E824FB1824F7BF9' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd2,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos1  2E824FB1824F7BF9
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2E824FB1824F7BF9
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Use `grub-mkconfig` to add the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be similar to [GRUB Rescue - setting boot and prefix again and again](https://askubuntu.com/a/888863/172838) and/or [How can I manually define the grub prefix variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483783/149903), the TLDR version of which is...

```bsh
## Is GRUB updated?
sudo update-grub
## Some systems may instead want...
# sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

## Is GRUB installed?
# sudo grub-install /dev/sd<some-letter>
```

... I say this because generally one only needs the commands you're using when in *rescue* mode.

The other thing that may be of interest while *digging* around GRUB options is...

```bsh
info -f grub -n 'Multi-boot manual config'
```

... among other informative documentation that may be found via the `info` command.

### Updates

Based off the updated question, I'll advise that ya copy the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` block to somewhere like *`/etc/grub.d/29_ms7`* and edit the *`29_ms7`* copy...

```
menuentry 'Grub Tests - Windows 7 (na /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-<Unique-ID-Stuff>' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd2,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos1  <Unique-ID-Stuff>
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <Unique-ID-Stuff>
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

> Side note, do **not** copy/paste above without editing things and reading up on the suggested `info` documentation, it's just pulled from your configs to *highlight* the important bits with minimal sanitation.

... after running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting there *should* be an additional Grub menu option. This new option and the copied config file are correlated because of updating Grub.

Edit the custom Grub menu file (if following along that'd be the *`/etc/grub.d/29_ms7`* file), update Grub, reboot the device, and repeat until ya no longer need the rescue mode.

> Hint, some of those `--hint-*` options might instead work better where some *`2`s* turned to *`0`s* and/or *`1`s* transmuted into *`7`s*.

I'm not quite sure what got messed up between what Grub automatically generated and how the MS OS is installed, but my guess is that there's some kind of re-partitioning/partition-resizing that took place in an *advance* menu during installation of Linux... did you by chance try to install Linux and Windows on the same hard-drive?

> > Windiws and Ubuntu are on same hard drive. Also this Ubuntu 18 is installed in place of Ubuntu 16 that I had couple of years with some grub config

That's **super** helpful to know!.

In the future it's a good idea to install different Operating Systems on separate storage media (I know that doesn't help in the present nor does), and when forced to share space it's a good idea to keep all the MS *stuff* at the *start* of the storage media's addressing scheme.

Focusing in on what can be done in the present, if ya check your `grub.cfg` file it makes use of `msdos7` within the...

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
# ...
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
```

... block, however, for some reason Grub is looking at `hd2` instead of `hd0` and within the `30_os-prober` it's looking for `msdos1` in addition to looking for `hd2`. In short something got *confused* as to how Operating Systems are to be found. So it is clear as to what kinds of edit's I'm suggesting...

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 -- Tests' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-<Unique-ID-Stuff>' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos7  <Unique-ID-Stuff>
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <Unique-ID-Stuff>
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

> Though, again, do **not** copy/past without consideration of available *`info`rmation* and modifications.

... while I may be **wrong** on some of the above edits, it's mainly to show where I'm suggesting edits take place within your own custom config file. It'll take a little *fiddling* to get things booting happily again, but with what's above and referencing the *`info`rmative* documentation I've faith ya can get things sorted soon.

Comment: Tried every of these and this not permanently set it :(. Ubuntu 18.4

Comment: Dang... can ya post your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file within your question then? Well minus anything ya thing is _sensitive_ as far as strings. You are running Grub2 right? I hope so, though that might be where you're running into issues... what file are you editing to add your OS boot?... hint if you're on Grub2 it likely _should_ be a custom file (one you've added or perhaps the installer has added), under the `/etc/grub.d/` directory.

Comment: Just updated main question with config file, and my grub version is (GRUB) 2.02-2

Comment: didn't tried your solution yet but yes Windiws and Ubuntu are on same hard drive. Also this Ubuntu 18 is installed in place of Ubuntu 16 that I had couple of years with some grub config

Comment: Thanks for all the updates @Sruj! I've updated my answer to provide a few more examples on building a custom Grub entry, if ya do a `more /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` it'll show that there's a `shell` script that is building that menu option on each update to Grub. That'll one day in the future _may be_ helpful, if ya ever want to get _fancy_ with Grub. For now though I'll still suggest testing a custom menu entry, put lots of comments (`#` prefixed lines) as ya learn... given latest info I'll further guess that the _upgrade_ to Ubuntu 18 succeeded **but** with errors; Linux boots from Grub?